# AUCTeX - delete 'other' files like .out, .aux, .log on successful compilation

Tags: auctex

I do not want to keep the miscellenous files created during compilation of my .tex files if the compilation is successful.

I tried setting `Latex-clean-output-suffixes` by adding these extensions but that did not help.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: The variable you're looking for is called `LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes`.  With the default setting, it covers `.out`, `.aux` and others.  You should achieve what you want just by hitting `C-c C-c RET Clean RET` without any customization.

Comment: @ArashEsbati That was perfect. Except that after `C-c C-c` there is no RET. It is `C-c C-c` clean RET. Will you please give this as an answer? I will then accept it. Others will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, the first `RET` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to customize anything.  The variable in question is called `LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes` and has the following default value:

> LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes is a variable defined in ‘latex.el’.
>   Its value is
>   `("\\.aux" "\\.bbl" "\\.blg" "\\.brf" "\\.fot" "\\.glo"`
>   `"\\.gls"  "\\.idx" "\\.ilg" "\\.ind" "\\.lof" "\\.log"`
>   `"\\.lot"  "\\.nav" "\\.out" "\\.snm" "\\.toc" "\\.url"`
>   `"\\.synctex\\.gz"  "\\.bcf" "\\.run\\.xml"    "\\.fls"`
>   `"-blx\\.bib"       "\\.acn" "\\.acr" "\\.alg" "\\.glg" "\\.ist")`

You can achieve want you want by hitting <kbd>C-c C-c Clean RET</kbd> or choose it in menu bar from `Command->Clean`.